# Unit Test Angular for HostListener

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I need to create unit test for @HostListener but I have no idea how to write it since it on top of component,

```
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) onDocumentClick(event) {
    if (this.activeEvent) {
      this.activeEvent = '';
    } else {
      this.showList = false;
    }
    this.resetDropdown(event.target.id);
  }
```

What is the best way write unit test for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
// feel free to change `body` to whatever you wish to send the click to
const body = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('body');
body.click();
// see if `onDocumentClick` gets called that way
```

Another option you have, since `@HostListener` is already tested by Angular, you can just call `onDocumentClick` with your mocked object.

```
const resetSpy = spyOn(component, 'resetDropdown');
const mockedEvent = { target: { id: 'xyz' } };
component.onDocumentClick(mockedEvent);
expect(resetSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('xyz');
```